# How to check if a string is obtainable using certain rules?

Tags: c++, string, dynamic-programming, cyk

It's been 1 week since I started trying to find a solution to this problem, and I ended up reading about CYK algorithm, but I can't understand how it would help me.

So I have a certain string from which I start, let's call it **startString**.
And I have a certain string to which I want to get by applying the later-explained rules, called **stopString**.

### -----------

Now let's take an example:

```
startString = "A"  
stopString = "2403"
```

This example's rules are the following:

```
A->BC  
B->D  
B->ED  
C->F  
C->FB  


E->0  
D->2  
D->3  
F->4  
E->1
```

The program will take the above input and output the minimal list of transformations applied to get from startString to stopString, which ***COULD BE*** the following:

```
A->BC, B->D, C->FB, B->ED, D->2, F->4, E->0, D->3
```

### -----------

My question is: How does CYK help me here? How do I obtain "2403" from "A" using CYK? Is there any simpler solution to this problem?

Comment: CYK is the hallmark solution for this problem.

Comment: Don't think about advanced parsing algorithms. Just write a parser. I'd start by rewriting the rules (they're simple) to rules with iteration.

Comment: Yeah, that much I know already. But how do I implement it ? All I could find about CYK was the matrix algorithm of checking whether a string is obtainable using a grammar. What is this grammar? And how do I obtain it from my rules?

Comment: Your "rules" are the grammar....Have you checked the wikipedia page on [CYK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CYK_algorithm)?

Comment: You need to write your grammar in Chomsky Normal Form before you can use CYK, though.

Comment: For example, B→D and B→ED together mean that a B is a possible E followed by a D, B→{E}D. That's easier to parse (for me). So that parse of the initial 2 is D, by your terminal rule, and that in turn is a B. Which in turn is part of an A or C.

Comment: @erip But it's pretty obvious it CAN be generated:    A->BC, B->D, C->FB, B->ED, D->2, F->4, E->0, D->3

Comment: @ijustpostedsomethingdumb Perhaps my grammar is wrong. I'll check.

Answer (score 0):

I'll start by writing your grammar in Chomsky Normal Form. There are currently two rules which aren't satisfying this property; namely

```
B->D
C->F
```

A naive way to fix this is to decay them into three rules:

```
B->2 
B->3 
C->4
```

Now your production rules are

```
A->BC  
B->ED  
B->2 
B->3 
C->4
C->FB  
D->2  
D->3  
E->0  
E->1 
F->4
```

The solver I'm using ([here](http://log-cse.blogspot.com/2014/01/cyk-algorithm-implementation.html)) doesn't allow numbers as terminals. Thus, I'll just create a bijective mapping

```
0 <-> a
1 <-> b
2 <-> c
3 <-> d
4 <-> e
```

The new target string is `"cead"` instead of `"2403"`. Plugging this into my solver yields the production rules.

```
Enter the start Variable A

Number of productions 11
A->BC
B->d
B->ED
C->e
C->FB
E->a
D->c
D->d
F->e
E->b
B->c

Enter string to be checked : cead
    A
          C
    A           B
   DB    CF     E    BD
String can be generated
```

Unfortunately, the rules are a little obscured because of the naive fix; however, I think this will suffice.

Comment: Yes, this seems about right. But how do I implement CNF-transformation?

Comment: [Here](https://people.cs.clemson.edu/~goddard/texts/theoryOfComputation/9a.pdf) are some slides that cover this topic.

Comment: Also, is there a way of avoiding CNF-transformation as it modifies the "rules" that I need to print?

Comment: @ijustpostedsomethingdumb You can write a different parser. CYK is the (typically) most efficient for parsing CFGs. You can write a recursive-descent parser, too, or a myriad of others. Recursive-descent is the easiest IMO.